# How Do I Print An Array With Attributes?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, attributes

I have this code so far...I created an array like this:

```
namespace animal_array
{

    class Program
    {

        struct animal
        {

            public string Name;

            public string Color;

            public int Weight;

            public int Age;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] Array = new int[5];
            animal cat;
            cat.name = "cat";
            cat.age = 2;
            cat.weight = 10;
            cat.color = "black";
```

and I do the same thing for four other animals...
and then I need a loop that will print out all the animal's info, and I think it would be something like this:

```
public static void printarray2 (int[] A) //print array function
{

    for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Name: " + A[i].name);
        Console.WriteLine("Weight: " + A[i].weight);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + A[i].age);
        Console.WriteLine("Color: " + A[i].color);
    }
}
```

But it won't let me do the .name, .color, etc. and I don't know how to fix the code. It says that the extensions don't exist in that context? So I'm not sure...

Comment: I think you want to use `animal[]` rather than `int[]`

Comment: This loop is in a separate method than the other code, which is in main. I was going to call this function in main and reference the animal array, but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you try this... `public static void printarray2 (animal[] A)`  ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either

Comment: In your code above `A` is an array of ints which don't have properties like .name and .weight.  It should be an array of animals to access those properties.  If you change it in method name you'll also need to change what you pass in to be an array of animals.

Comment: In addition to what was already said about `int` arrays, your class clear has properties called `Name`, `Age`, etc. Yet your code has `name`, `age`, etc. C# is case sEnSiTiVe

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
public class Program
{

    // Animal
    public struct Animal
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Color;
        public int Weight;
        public int Age;
    }

    // Main
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];

        animals[0] = new Animal { Name = "Cat", Color = "Grey", Weight = 20, Age = 7  };
        animals[1] = new Animal { Name = "Dog", Color = "Grey", Weight = 20, Age = 7 };
        animals[2] = new Animal { Name = "Horse", Color = "Grey", Weight = 20, Age = 7 };
        animals[3] = new Animal { Name = "Rabbit", Color = "Grey", Weight = 20, Age = 7 };
        animals[4] = new Animal { Name = "Mouse", Color = "Grey", Weight = 20, Age = 7 };

        OutputAnimals(animals);
    }

    // Print out animals
    public static void OutputAnimals(Animal[] A)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + A[i].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Weight: " + A[i].Weight);
            Console.WriteLine("Age: " + A[i].Age);
            Console.WriteLine("Color: " + A[i].Color);
        }

    }
}
```

It's using an array of `Animal` rather than `int` and has fixed the case on the properties, e.g. `.name` becomes `.Name`.  Also replaced the hardcoded 5 in the loop with `A.Length`.